# Socket.io spams errors in browser console

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Is it possible to hide this type of errors in socket.io/javascript ?

[image]

I have tried

```
    socket.on('connect_error', function (error) {
        return errorHandler(error);
    });
```

but handling like this only allows me to take actions with my app in case of error, but browser console still full of errors.

this errors are fired by connection attempt to socket.io server with this code

```
    socket = io.connect(
        settings.requestUri,
        {
            query: 'token=' + settings.requestToken,
            reconnectionDelay: 500,
            reconnectionAttempts: 15
        }
    );
```

Comment: Socket.io is trying to make the requests to update/refresh data from your database, but you make the request from another domain than yuor api is, so therefore the CORS errors. modify your API to accept CORS requests or move the Script on same domain as the API. This is just an idea on what you shown. Also the errors are not thrown by Socket.io, they are thrown by the browser as a response from the server(api).

Comment: These errors need to be addressed for your app to work correctly, you can't just simply disregard them. You are trying to make a request to get some data via an XMLHttpRequest but the server you are trying to hit (looks like your own) doesn't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Have a look at how you set that up. As for the first error with socket.io can you elaborate further on the issue with some example code?

Comment: thank you DincaAdrian and JackThompson, i added some code to make things clear, this errors are fired after connection attempt, and i dont know how to handle them, because even first attempt is already firing errors.